# JSON Schema Validator and Converter in Java

Tags: json, jsonschema

I  have two requirements:

1. Validate a `org.json.JSONObject` against a schema (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03)
2. Convert one `org.json.JSONObject` or its String representation to another `org.json.JSONObject`. For example, convert

   {
   "field1":"value1",
   "field2":"value2"
   }

to

```
{ 
   "field3":"value1",
   "field4":"value1"
}
```

The mapping will be something like:

```
field1=field3
field2=field4
```

Answer (score 2):

(disclaimer: I am the author of one such library)

In Java, there is [this library](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) that I wrote, but it uses Jackson at its core, not org.json.

However, this is not a problem, you can use `JsonLoader` to convert JSONObject:

```
JsonNode schema = JsonLoader.fromString(object1.toString());
JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(object2.toString());
```

And then use the API.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how do I validate json data against a json schema file with `json-schema-validator`. So far I tried this with `JsonTools`, unfortunately no success. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18143650/1817029

Comment: Depends on what version you are using. Have you had a look [here](http://fge.github.io/json-schema-validator/devel/com/github/fge/jsonschema/examples/package-frame.html) (note: devel version)?

Comment: Thank you, this looks quite simple. I have downloded the devel version: `json-schema-validator-2.1.7.jar` and added to the build path (Eclipse IDE), but now I'm getting the errors:
`The import com.github.fge.jsonschema.exceptions.ProcessingException cannot be resolved` and `The import com.fasterxml cannot be resolved` 
Are there any additional libs?

Comment: Yes there are. But don't you use gradle or maven for dependencies?

Comment: No :( Is there a download site, where I can find the appropriate dependencies. Or is there no way around maven?

Comment: Well, the best way around maven is gradle, really. But I'd have thought Eclipse had the ability to use a repository to find/manage dependencies (I use IDEA which does). If you can get the source from github, then it's as simple as `./gradlew fatJar` and include `libs/json-schema-validator-*-farJar.jar` as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You could try these:

1. You may try using [JSON Tools](http://jsontools.berlios.de/)
2. Did not get your 2nd question but if you are looking for string equivalent then you could use [JSONObject.toString()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

For your second requirement, you may consider `GSON` by Google.

Here is a cookbook style [tutorial](http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/) to get you started with GSON. It shows you how you can parse a JSON string into a Java object.